# list of pointers in c++

Tags: c++, list, pointers

What i want to do is

```
for (list<cPacket *>::iterator i = cache.begin(); i != cache.end(); i++){
        if( strcmp(i->getName(),id) == 0 ){
            return true;
        }
}
```

where `getName` is function of the class cPacket, But it does not work, i tries also 
`i.operator->()->getName()`, and again nothing.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: @Fred, I just looked over your edits. He doesn't what the problem is (besides vaguely "not working"), and you fixed a compiler problem by changing `list::iterator` to `list<cPacket *>::iterator` editing his code. Wouldn't that have been better to do in an answer?

Comment: I changed no such thing.  The template arguments were not displayed because the code was not formatted, and they were getting stripped as bad HTML.  Look at the source of the original edit.  All I did was code formatting.

Answer (score 8):

```
(*i)->getName()
```

is what you are looking for.

Comment: @pavlos: You can think of the iterator as a pointer to an element of your container.  But in this case, the elements in the container are pointers.  `(*i)` will give you the pointer from your container, and then you can use `->getName()` to call the function on the object it's pointing to.

Comment: *i dereferences a pointer, or in this case, dereferences an iterator.  It's very similar to the -> operator - instead of ptr->getName(), you could also do (*ptr).getName().  In this case, since you have an iterator containing a pointer, you first dereference the iterator using *, then dereference the pointer using ->.

Comment: sorry again, but i tried as you said, and then add this lines:

void ProxyServer::addURLToCache( cPacket *url ){
 
 if( numOfUrlsInCache < 3 ){
  cache.push_back( url );
  numOfUrlsInCache++;
 }
 else
  EV<<"Cache is full"<<endl;
}

and then when i try to iterate again it crashes! What is this about.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing more of your code.  It could be that *url is NULL or an invalid pointer.  Trying to dereference a null pointer can cause a crash.

Answer (score 6):

`*i` dereferences the iterator. As the data type of the list is `pointer to cPacket`, you need to apply the `->` operator to access its members. Parentheses are needed for proper precendence:

```
(*i)->whatever()
```

Answer (score -3):

replace

```
list<cPacket *>::iterator i
```

with

```
list<cPacket>*::iterator i
```

Comment: The type `list<cPacket>*::iterator` is syntactically illegal, not to mention the fact that it is not equivalent to the return type of `cache.begin()` and `cache.end()`. That's two reasons why it won't compile.